# Obtaining the polar plot of an antenna array factor

Tags: graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

For an engineering problem I am trying to obtain the polar plot of an 'antenna factor' function by hand. The function for the array factor is given as:

$$f(\Psi) = \frac{sin(N\frac{\Psi}{2})}{Nsin(\frac{\Psi}{2})}$$

Where $\Psi = \beta dcos(\theta) + \alpha$

For this particular problem $N=5$, and $d=0.35\lambda$. I worked out $\alpha=0.7\pi$ and $\beta d = \frac{2 \pi}{\lambda}\times0.35\lambda = 0.7 \pi$

Substituting $\Psi = 0.7\pi cos(\theta) + 0.7 \pi$ into the formula for the array factor gives

$$f(\theta) = \frac{sin(5\frac{0.7\pi cos(\theta) + 0.7 \pi}{2})}{5sin(\frac{0.7\pi cos(\theta) + 0.7 \pi}{2})}$$

I am not allowed to use any computing tools for this exercise and so I am trying to plot the function by hand. When I substitute values for $\theta$ I don't get what I expect, the values that result are always close to 1, such as 0.994 for $\theta =0^\circ$ and $0.994$ for $\theta = 30^\circ$. The array factor for this problem should look as the polar plot below. Could someone please help me with how to obtain the polar plot for this function given the formula above.

[image: Array factor]

Comment: See that $\pi$ in your formula? $\theta$ in your formula is in radians, not degrees. But since you give $\theta$ in degrees later on, you probably are calculating $\sin$ in degrees. Either switch to using all radians, including on your calculator, or else replace $\pi$ in your formula with $180^{\circ}$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you. I'm quite embarrassed I made that mistake.

Comment: FYI - when I plugged your formula into [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), it graphed that second largest loop inside the main loop, instead of opposite like your answer shows. There may be another problem.